# setuptools.setup() install_requires not installing listed packages

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I'm using:

```
python 3.7.4
setuptools 50.3.0
pip 20.2.3
```

I have a public github repository that I'm trying to turn into a package to install. It needs `requests` to work properly.

The relevant files are organized like this:

```
package
    __init__.py
    __version__.py
    functions.py
setup.py
```

This is in each file:

```
# __init__.py

from .functions import first_function, second_function
```

```
# __version__.py

# version, title, etc. are defined here
__requests__ = 'requests>=2,<3'
```

```
# setup.py

import setuptools

from package.__version__ import __requests__, ...

setuptools.setup(
    ...,
    install_requires=[__requests__]
)
```

When I try to install with `pip install git+https://github.com/<user>/<repository name>.git@<version tag>`, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`.

I've already looked through several popular github repositories (like `requests` and `pandas`), the pypa sample project on github, the documentation for `setuptools`, and many github issues plus stackoverflow questions, but I still haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

importing your code during `setup.py` will fail because your dependencies won't be installed (essentially you've created a cycle from `setup.py instal_requires` -> your code -> requests needing to be installed)

there's ~2 approaches to solving this

one is to read your dependencies at runtime using `importlib.metadata` (this is what I'd suggest!)

```py
if sys.version_info >= (3, 8):
    import importlib.metadata as importlib_metadata
else:
    import importlib_metadata  # pip install importlib-metadata backport

dist = importlib_metadata.distribution('yourpackage')
# this is a list for example
# >>> importlib.metadata.distribution('pre-commit').requires
# ['cfgv>=2.0.0', 'identify>=1.0.0', 'nodeenv>=0.11.1', 'pyyaml>=5.1', 'toml', 'virtualenv>=20.0.8', 'importlib-resources; python_version < "3.7"', 'importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8"']
__requests__, = [req for req in dist.requires if req.startswith('requests>=')]
```

the other option is to read your `__init__.py` instead of importing it and parsing it manually:

for example:

```py
import ast

with open('myproject/__init__.py', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('__requests__ ='):
            requests_version = ast.literal_eval(line.split('=')[1])
            break
    else:
        raise AssertionError(f'__requests__ = not found in {f.name}')
```

I'd suggest the former personally though I've seen both approaches taken for various reasons

Comment: I went with the second option since I'm more familiar with reading files, but I'll try to look into the metadata stuff when I have more time. Thanks! The installation worked.